# How to cache webview in react-native

Tags: react-native, caching, webview

I'm currently using WebView component to render a website inside my app but I also want to cache that website so that it can be opened even when there is no internet and also how to remove that cache whenever needed. 
Please suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have: [react-native-offline-cache-webview](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-offline-cache-webview)

It can cache your WebView for offline consulting, and it works for Android and iOS.

Example app [here](https://github.com/zhangtaii/react-native-offline-cache-webview/tree/master/example)

Comment: not working and not maintained for current configurations